# Is "if (somestring in {'oneoption':false, 'secondoption':false})" considered bad practise in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

The title basically. Does such construct considered bad practice or could lead to some unexpected behavior in javascript?

```
if (e.target.name in {name: '', number: ''}) {
  // do something
}
```

It checks if HTMLNode attribute name exists in "object" keys and proceeds in case it does. Basic check if clicked thing is one we need. 
Does it performs better\worse than something like this?

```
if(['name','number'].some(a=>a==e.target.name)) {
  // do something
}
```

Optimal way to do such checks both typing and performance wise?

Comment: This might get better results on the code review site.

Comment: Write a small Node.js program to micro-benchmark your code. However, in an actual application the speed difference is likely negligible (since everything else you do with the DOM is more expensive).

Comment: `"toString" in { "foo" : "" }`

Comment: This is an opinion-based question and thus it's off-topic for SO. (But **yes**, those are both bad practice. They're obtuse, error-prone, and in theory create and throw away objects unnecessarily. The simple pair of `==` expressions, on the other hand, is clear, idiomatic, memory-neutral...)

Comment: If you want better performance, the primary optimisation is to move the array literal/object/set/whatever-you'll-be-using outside of the `if` statement into a static variable so that it is not re-evalated and re-constructed every single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be problematic because the `in` operator checks in all the prototype chain, and therefore you could get an unexpected positive.

```
"constructor" in {name: '', number: ''} // true  !!
```

You can use a set if you still want constant performance, but for small cases [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is probably more readable.

```
new Set(['name', 'number']).has(e.target.name);
```

```
['name', 'number'].includes(e.target.name);
```

Comment: It's unlikely though that an DOM element tag name is one of the built-in object functions though.

Comment: @FelixKling The OP uses `name`, not `tagName`. The value can be an arbitrary string, so it's possible it could appear in `Object.prototype`.

Comment: I stand corrected!